# Understanding Pingdom DNS test results

Tags: dns

I recently got the domain lepinard.com transfered to me from a web agency. 
I changed the DNS several weeks ago, but ever since it's not fully propagated.
I get various errors when I try a DNS test, but I'm not sure what I should do to solve the problem.
Please could you take a look at the test results and let me know. Thanks.
http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=lepinard.com

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to make sure the DNS records at `sdns2.ovh.net` and at `thor.groupemaurizi.ovh` are the same. 
Currently `sdns2.ovh.net` is returning only one NS record: `ns206289.ovh.net`, but the other one is returning 2 (which seems to be the proper servers).

If you don't know how to solve the issue you can contact the support of `OVH`.

Answer (score 0):

Pingdom has identified 2 major issues -

1. Superfluous name server listed at parent:
2. SOA records found.

Both these issues seems to be because - With your registrar you have given only one DNS server, you should add both DNS server entries. And the issue should go away.